# awk sum values of a column, if other columns remain constant

Tags: awk, sum

I have a file (example.csv) with around 5M rows, each row containing 4 columns (user, day, type, value), like this:

```
user1,2022-01-01,type1,0.1
user1,2022-01-01,type1,0.9
user1,2022-01-02,type1,1.0
user1,2022-01-02,type2,1.0
user2,2022-01-01,type1,1.0
user2,2022-01-01,type2,1.0
user3,2022-01-01,type1,0.3
user3,2022-01-01,type1,0.2
user3,2022-01-01,type1,0.5
```

I would like to sum the values (4th column in this example) that correspond to the same user, day and type, so the expected output should look like this:

```
user1,2022-01-01,type1,1.0
user1,2022-01-02,type1,1.0
user1,2022-01-02,type2,1.0
user2,2022-01-01,type1,1.0
user2,2022-01-01,type2,1.0
user3,2022-01-01,type1,1.0
```

I tried something like this to try if it works

```
awk -F"," '!seen[$1]++;&&!seen[$2]++;&&!seen[$3]++;sum+=$4{print sum}' example.csv
```

but I am still far from the correct solution.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, post a proper sample data with summable values and the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: I have changed the sample data as requested, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}
{
    a[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3]+=$4
}
END {
    for(i in a) 
        print i,sprintf("%.1f",a[i])
}' file
```

Output:

```
user2,2022-01-01,type1,1.0
user2,2022-01-01,type2,1.0
user1,2022-01-01,type1,1.0
user3,2022-01-01,type1,1.0
user1,2022-01-02,type1,1.0
user1,2022-01-02,type2,1.0
```

The output order is awk implementation dependent. If needed, use `sort` or [GNU AWK's `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html).